# Parse soap msg with gSOAP

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap

I have following example xml message:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <to>...</to>
        <from>...</from>
        <id>..</id>
        <relatesTo>...</relatesTo>
        <action>...</action>
        <version>...</version>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <customComplexElement>
            <a>a_v</a>
            <b>b_v</b>
            <c>c_v</c>
            <d>d_v</d>
            <e>e_v</e>
            <f>f_v</f>
        </customComplexElement>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

From which I have generated a xsd file with use of one of online tools:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></import>
  <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="relatesTo" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="action" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="customComplexElement">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="a"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="b"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="c"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="d"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="e"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="f"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then I generate the appropriate header file with wsdl2h.exe and then compile it with soapcpp2.exe compiler.
Then I try to read xml file with a function soap_read_customComplexElement() and all I get is SOAP_TAG_MISMATCH. This method seems to work if I get rid of all the soap stuff the message but I wonder if there are some functions in gSOAP to parse soap envelope, header and body?

Answer (score 2):

I've had same problem. But i've just fixed it.
So, in my case i use this line of code.

```
struct soap *soap = soap_new1(SOAP_C_UTFSTRING | SOAP_XML_IGNORENS | SOAP_XML_TREE);
```

The key paramter is **SOAP_XML_IGNORENS**. This parameter ignore namespaces.

```
SOAP_XML_IGNORENS   in: ignores the use of XML namespaces in input
```

The root of this problem is that you don't declare namespaces in your body content. That why gSoap don't know how to convert this xml.

This wouldn't be converted, because gSoap don't know what is ns4:

```
<ns4:ParseKeywords><ns4:Keyword>Hello</ns4:Keyword></ns4:ParseKeywords>
```

But if i declare namespace it will be converted

```
<ns4:ParseKeywords xmlns:ns4="com.idurdyev.idcommerce:ParseKeywords:1.0"><ns4:Keyword>Hello</ns4:Keyword></ns4:ParseKeywords>
```